How to remove specific post type indexes from Yoast sitemap_index.xml
I used Yoast's API to create a custom XML sitemap that combines all of my website pages and a few other post types into one. I do the same thing for translated pages so that they are in their own sitemap.
I want to remove the Yoast-created XML sitemaps from the sitemap_index.xml so only my custom sitemap is there. I cannot find any references to how to accomplish this. I tried using the wpseo_sitemap_exclude_post_type filter to remove the post types for the other sitemaps, but doing so removed my custom sitemap from the sitemap index as well (since it is comprised of the same post types that I excluded).
Is there any way to do this? This screenshot shows what I'm talking about, I want to remove https://mywebsite.kinsta.cloud/page-sitemap.xml and https://mywebsite.kinsta.cloud/people-sitemap.xml from the sitemap index and just have https://mywebsite.kinsta.cloud/fullsite-sitemap.xml and https://mywebsite.kinsta.cloud/es/fullsite-sitemap.xml.


You can use the below code on the functions.php file:
function yoast_sitemap_exclude_post_type_sp( $value, $post_type ) {

    // remove post_type : product, post, page

    if ( $post_type == 'product' || $post_type == 'post' || $post_type == 'page') {
        return true;
    }
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_post_type', 'yoast_sitemap_exclude_post_type_sp', 10, 2 );


[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/0k4bAmIC.png


How does this solve the issue? Please explain what you've you changed to address the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers

Also, I mentioned in my description that I already tried using the wpseo_sitemap_exclude_post_type filter to exclude the "page" and "people" post types, but doing so caused my custom sitemaps to disappear from the index as well.
